# TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 are not working with cURL and PHP

Tags: curl, tls1.2

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false) 
{ echo curl_error($ch); }
else 
{ echo 'Operation completed without any errors'; }

curl_close($ch);
return $xml;
```

Above code was working fine without any issue until last few days. But now suddenly above code is giving below error.

> Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.site.com:443

As per suggested by many people that below code will resolve above issue but it is not helping. Still getting same error.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); //for TLSv1.2
```

Below info is mentioned in php info.

```
 phpinfo() - libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8q zlib/1.2.3
```

Please suggest what is wrong or missing with my code.

Thank you,

Comment: i've seen this problem countless times. it's a bug in your tls/curl lib. update openssl/libcurl, because you're encountering a probably-long-since-fixed bug in 1 of those

Comment: @hanshenrik, Ok I will contact my hosting server about this and will see what they are saying.